# how do i receive messages sent to gtalk?

Tags: c#

im making an application that needs to get received messages that were sent to google chat. is there an api for working with google chat?

can someone please give me an example in C# how do i receive gtalk messages? im sorry the xmpp documentation is too complex and i do not understand where to start

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe that Gtalk uses the Jabber/XMPP protocol.

You can find more information on it here: http://xmpp.org/protocols/

Here is a list of APIs you may find useful:
http://xmpp.org/software/libraries.shtml